# The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received null

Tags: visual-studio-code, nodemon

I am running npm run dev code in vscode to start my site and I am getting the following error how do I solve it?

```
TypeError: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received null
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at prepareSecretKey (node:internal/crypto/keys:580:11)
    at new Hmac (node:internal/crypto/hash:132:9)
    at Object.createHmac (node:crypto:162:10)
    at hmacSha256 (C:\Users\gulct\Desktop\mappix\MapPix-Backend-V0.0.1 Beta\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:191:17)
    at Hi (C:\Users\gulct\Desktop\mappix\MapPix-Backend-V0.0.1 Beta\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:195:13)
    at Object.continueSession (C:\Users\gulct\Desktop\mappix\MapPix-Backend-V0.0.1 Beta\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:40:24)
    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (C:\Users\gulct\Desktop\mappix\MapPix-Backend-V0.0.1 Beta\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:257:10)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Connection.emit (node:domain:475:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I didn't do anything because I don't know the solution to the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find a fix?